# Airflow FileSensor : Not able to sense the file with Airflow FileSensor Operator

Tags: python, airflow

I am new to apache airflow.
I am trying to implement the airflow fileSensor Task.

Its working when creating the connection for local where airflow is installed.
When creating the connection as FS connection for external server (moveit).

It is continuously poking the file but not sensing.

Please find the logs below along with the code.

Code :

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.contrib.operators.ssh_operator import SSHOperator
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
from airflow.sensors.filesystem import FileSensor
from airflow.exceptions import AirflowSensorTimeout
from datetime import timedelta, datetime
from airflow.models import Variable


default_args = {
    'owner': 'Airflow_nl',
    'depends_on_past': True,
    'email': [Variable.get("env_short_nl9_dspnsd_rx_notification_email")],
    'start_date': datetime(2021, 9, 6),
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'email_on_retry': True
    , 'retries': 1  # The number of retries performed before the task fails
    , 'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5)  # The delay between retries.
    # , 'queue': 'cds_queue'
    #, 'pool': 'env_short_nl9_cds_summary_pool'
    # , 'priority_weight': 10
    # , 'execution_timeout': 24                                    # The maximum time a task should be able to run - the task will fail if it runs for more than this time.
    # , 'end_date': datetime(2016, 1, 1)                           # The date the DAG should stop running, usually set as none.
}

dag = DAG(dag_id='env_short_nl9_dspnsd_rx_KNMPProductLoad', max_active_runs=1, default_args=default_args,
          schedule_interval=None, catchup=False)

NL9_APPS = Variable.get("env_short_nl9_dspnsd_rx_apps_path")

process_stg_bash = """
#!/bin/bash
sh -x {0}/dspnsd-rx/current/scripts/sparkPipeline/nl9_dspnsd_rx_knmpReferenceDataLoad.sh {0}/dspnsd-rx/current/scripts/loadAsset.properties """.format(NL9_APPS)

task_pcmdty_knmp_load_Trigger = SSHOperator(task_id='nl9_dspnsd_rx_KNMPProductStageLoadTrigger',
                                            ssh_conn_id='env_short_nl9_dspnsd_rx_edge_node_ssh',
                                            command=process_stg_bash,
                                            wait_for_downstream=True,
                                            dag=dag)



task_knmp_file_sensor = FileSensor(task_id = 'file_sensor_knmp',
                                   poke_interval = 10,
                                   filepath = 'test.txt',
                                   fs_conn_id = 'tritonairflowtest',
                                   dag = dag)


task_knmp_file_sensor >> task_pcmdty_knmp_load_Trigger
```

Logs :

```
[2021-09-20 07:54:29,905] {taskinstance.py:896} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: devl_nl9_dspnsd_rx_KNMPProductLoad.file_sensor_knmp 2021-09-20T07:54:29.262557+00:00 [queued]>
[2021-09-20 07:54:29,971] {taskinstance.py:896} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: devl_nl9_dspnsd_rx_KNMPProductLoad.file_sensor_knmp 2021-09-20T07:54:29.262557+00:00 [queued]>
[2021-09-20 07:54:29,972] {taskinstance.py:1087} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2021-09-20 07:54:29,972] {taskinstance.py:1088} INFO - Starting attempt 1 of 2
[2021-09-20 07:54:29,972] {taskinstance.py:1089} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2021-09-20 07:54:29,990] {taskinstance.py:1107} INFO - Executing <Task(FileSensor): file_sensor_knmp> on 2021-09-20T07:54:29.262557+00:00
[2021-09-20 07:54:30,004] {standard_task_runner.py:52} INFO - Started process 482200 to run task
[2021-09-20 07:54:30,016] {standard_task_runner.py:76} INFO - Running: ['airflow', 'tasks', 'run', 'devl_nl9_dspnsd_rx_KNMPProductLoad', 'file_sensor_knmp', '2021-09-20T07:54:29.262557+00:00', '--job-id', '1831', '--pool', 'default_pool', '--raw', '--subdir', 'DAGS_FOLDER/devl_nl9_dspnsd_rx_KNMPProductLoad.py', '--cfg-path', '/tmp/tmpyzvq0vsm', '--error-file', '/tmp/tmp3efvjtyg']
[2021-09-20 07:54:30,019] {standard_task_runner.py:77} INFO - Job 1831: Subtask file_sensor_knmp
[2021-09-20 07:54:30,144] {logging_mixin.py:104} INFO - Running <TaskInstance: devl_nl9_dspnsd_rx_KNMPProductLoad.file_sensor_knmp 2021-09-20T07:54:29.262557+00:00 [running]> on host ab2e23c71b82
[2021-09-20 07:54:30,323] {taskinstance.py:1302} INFO - Exporting the following env vars:
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_EMAIL=vlingala@in.imshealth.com
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_OWNER=Airflow_nl
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_ID=devl_nl9_dspnsd_rx_KNMPProductLoad
AIRFLOW_CTX_TASK_ID=file_sensor_knmp
AIRFLOW_CTX_EXECUTION_DATE=2021-09-20T07:54:29.262557+00:00
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_RUN_ID=manual__2021-09-20T07:54:29.262557+00:00
[2021-09-20 07:54:30,356] {base.py:78} INFO - Using connection to: id: devl_nl9_dspnsd_rx_edge_node_ssh. Host: 10.91.193.170, Port: 22, Schema: , Login: nl9dusr, Password: ***, extra: {'path': '/home/nl9dusr/test'}
[2021-09-20 07:54:30,357] {filesystem.py:55} INFO - Poking for file /home/nl9dusr/test/test.txt
[2021-09-20 07:54:40,391] {base.py:78} INFO - Using connection to: id: devl_nl9_dspnsd_rx_edge_node_ssh. Host: 10.91.193.170, Port: 22, Schema: , Login: nl9dusr, Password: ***, extra: {'path': '/home/nl9dusr/test'}
[2021-09-20 07:54:40,393] {filesystem.py:55} INFO - Poking for file /home/nl9dusr/test/test.txt
[2021-09-20 07:54:50,426] {base.py:78} INFO - Using connection to: id: devl_nl9_dspnsd_rx_edge_node_ssh. Host: 10.91.193.170, Port: 22, Schema: , Login: nl9dusr, Password: ***, extra: {'path': '/home/nl9dusr/test'}
[2021-09-20 07:54:50,427] {filesystem.py:55} INFO - Poking for file /home/nl9dusr/test/test.txt
[2021-09-20 07:55:00,460] {base.py:78} INFO - Using connection to: id: devl_nl9_dspnsd_rx_edge_node_ssh. Host: 10.91.193.170, Port: 22, Schema: , Login: nl9dusr, Password: ***, extra: {'path': '/home/nl9dusr/test'}
[2021-09-20 07:55:00,460] {filesystem.py:55} INFO - Poking for file /home/nl9dusr/test/test.txt
[2021-09-20 07:55:10,487] {base.py:78} INFO - Using connection to: id: devl_nl9_dspnsd_rx_edge_node_ssh. Host: 10.91.193.170, Port: 22, Schema: , Login: nl9dusr, Password: ***, extra: {'path': '/home/nl9dusr/test'}
[2021-09-20 07:55:10,488] {filesystem.py:55} INFO - Poking for file /home/nl9dusr/test/test.txt
[2021-09-20 07:55:20,523] {base.py:78} INFO - Using connection to: id: devl_nl9_dspnsd_rx_edge_node_ssh. Host: 10.91.193.170, Port: 22, Schema: , Login: nl9dusr, Password: ***, extra: {'path': '/home/nl9dusr/test'}
[2021-09-20 07:55:20,524] {filesystem.py:55} INFO - Poking for file /home/nl9dusr/test/test.txt
[2021-09-20 07:55:30,549] {base.py:78} INFO - Using connection to: id: devl_nl9_dspnsd_rx_edge_node_ssh. Host: 10.91.193.170, Port: 22, Schema: , Login: nl9dusr, Password: ***, extra: {'path': '/home/nl9dusr/test'}
[2021-09-20 07:55:30,550] {filesystem.py:55} INFO - Poking for file /home/nl9dusr/test/test.txt
[2021-09-20 07:55:40,578] {base.py:78} INFO - Using connection to: id: devl_nl9_dspnsd_rx_edge_node_ssh. Host: 10.91.193.170, Port: 22, Schema: , Login: nl9dusr, Password: ***, extra: {'path': '/home/nl9dusr/test'}
[2021-09-20 07:55:40,579] {filesystem.py:55} INFO - Poking for file /home/nl9dusr/test/test.txt
[2021-09-20 07:55:50,613] {base.py:78} INFO - Using connection to: id: devl_nl9_dspnsd_rx_edge_node_ssh. Host: 10.91.193.170, Port: 22, Schema: , Login: nl9dusr, Password: ***, extra: {'path': '/home/nl9dusr/test'}
[2021-09-20 07:55:50,614] {filesystem.py:55} INFO - Poking for file /home/nl9dusr/test/test.txt
```

Can you Please help me here.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Which airflow version, and what kind of remote FS connection are you using?

Comment: Airflow Version: 2.1.1
Remote FS connection : I am trying to sense the file in linux file system